# how to get value of Multiple text inputs with same name

Tags: php, html, forms

i have just created one form that have some input fields with the same name . i want store all those value in one variable after submitting a form .

the code is

```
      <div class="selectContainer">
        <label>Number Of Person:</label>
      <select id="ddTest" name="person">
         <option value="">select</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>

        <option value="2">2</option>

        <option value="3">3</option>

        <option value="4">4</option>

        <option value="5">5</option>

        <option value="6">6</option>
         </select>

       </div>
        <div class="hidden is1">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="1">remove</a>

    <label>Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" >
   <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >

</div>

    <div class="hidden is2">
    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
    </div>

         <div class="hidden is2">
        <a href="#" class="remove" rel="2">remove</a>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" >
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" >
        </div>

         <div class="hidden is3">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="3">remove</a>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

         <div class="hidden is3">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="3">remove</a>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

         <div class="hidden is3">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="3">remove</a>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
          </div>


          <div class="hidden is4">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="4">remove</a>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
          </div>


         <div class="hidden is4">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="4">remove</a>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

         <div class="hidden is4">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="4">remove</a>
          <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
          </div>

         <div class="hidden is4">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="4">remove</a>   
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
        </div>
        <div class="hidden is5">
         <a href="#" class="remove" rel="5">remove</a>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

          <div class="hidden is5">
           <a href="#" class="remove" rel="5">remove</a>
         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

          <div class="hidden is5">
           <a href="#" class="remove" rel="5">remove</a>
          <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

          <div class="hidden is5">
           <a href="#" class="remove" rel="5">remove</a>
          <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
         </div>

          <div class="hidden is5">
           <a href="#" class="remove" rel="5">remove</a>

         <label>Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" >
         <label>Age</label>
         <input type="text" name="age" >
        </div>`
```

how to store this value in one variable .? please help i am new to php

Comment: Take array of same name. Like name="name[]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
 $age = $_POST['age'];

for($l=0; $l < count($name); $l++)
 { //your condition
}
```

don't forget to add this in your html

```
 <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" size="20" name="name[]" id="name"   >
     </td>
  <td>
 <label>Age</label>
<input type="text" size="20" name="age[]" id="age"  >
   </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an array using `[]` for all similar names:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" >
<input type="text" name="age[]" >
```

And then you can iterate over them:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= count($_POST['name']); $i++) {
   echo $_POST['name'][$i] . "<br>";
   echo $_POST['age'][$i] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it, poster this is your answer^

Comment: you can store in one field using serialize

Comment: @Nayana: That's differnt question, you need to ask how to store values in db in another question, if you search on google, you will see thousands of tutorials on how to store values in db via php.

Comment: its showing error (Uninitialized string offset: 0 )

Comment: if you count `name` how do you use `age` in the same `for` without counting age ? (instead use `foreach()`)

Comment: @nayna you have to do like $name = $_POST['name'][$j]; and store $name value in database field inside loop or you directly use $_POST['name']['$i'] in query field